# Create checkboxlist dynamically and insert into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created `Labels`, `CheckBoxes`......
but I want to store the CheckBox values as 0 or 1 for 'on' or 'off' into sql server after check.....
how can I??

```
   protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_TB.Text);

        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = dt.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            newcheck.AutoPostBack = true;
            newcheck.CausesValidation = false;
            newcheck.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(newcheck_CheckedChanged);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }

        con.Close();
    }

    void newcheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox currentCheckbox = sender as CheckBox;
        string extractInteger = Regex.Match(currentCheckbox.ID, @"\d+").Value;
        Label currentlabel = (Label)Labeldiv.FindControl("Label" + extractInteger);
        con.Open();

        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDay", currentlabel.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventStatus", currentCheckbox.Checked ? "true" : "false");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

the checkboxes must create based on the ddl selection.... If we select 6 then 6 checkboxes must create, after that when we check the checkbox then the values must store into the sql-server....

The values did not stored into sql server......

Comment: Now that I notice, this code looks weird... What's the purpose of the checkboxes ? You never give them a chance to be actually checked (flow is: create checkbox -> read checkbox -> write to db). The outcome will always be 'off' (or 0).

Comment: Where are you declaring the `cmd2` that is being called in `CheckBox_CheckedChanged`?  Because it looks like you're declaring a **new** `cmd2` in the for-loop that is only local to the for-loop

Comment: Post edit... you are now updating the cmd2 parameters on each loop of the for-loop.  That means that at the end of it, ONLY the last item will be saved

Comment: The cmd2 seems to be declared globally. Which is weird. Even weirder, he opens the connection in one event without closing it, then reusing it in another event. Terrible design.

Comment: I agree @Tobberoth, it is not properly thought out

Comment: both events are different ;)

Comment: I have created Labels & checkboxes based on the selection of the DropDownList, And these values must store after checked only into the sql server

Comment: "After Checked only" means when do you really want to save the results. when user press some button or when some event Triggers?

Comment: the checkboxes must create based on the ddl selection.... If we select 6 then 6 checkboxes must create, after that when we check the checkbox then the values must store into the sql-server.. see my code in Question, I have edited...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EventStatus` is a numeric column, the laziest solution I can think of is

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventStatus", newcheck.Checked ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: @user2971566: even if it checked??

Comment: I've added a comment to the question itself

Comment: Have you tried it with all relevant code inside CheckBox_CheckedChanged instead? The way it's written in your question is very weird, you're not even opening your connection when running the command.